# java.util.MissingResourceException when getBundle()

Tags: java, properties, bundle

Good day to all, I'm trying to start working with bundle, but it crashes `Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name locals, locale ru`

here's the code:

```
 ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("locals",Locale.forLanguageTag("RU"), new UTF8Control());
```

I also tried to get a bundle basename like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("production\\src\\sample\\locals.properties");
    ResourceBundle rb=new PropertyResourceBundle(fis);
    System.out.println(rb.getBaseBundleName());
```

But this outputs null, although I can work with keys.
For example this displays a list of all keys:

```
Enumeration<String> enumeration = rb.getKeys();
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println("" + enumeration.nextElement());
    }
```

It is worth noting that the bundle properties file is located in the same package from where I am trying to get the bundle.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSq6Z.png)

I would like to know how to get rid of `java.util.MissingResourceException` and why `getBaseBundleName()` outputs null when the bundle is non-empty

Comment: Are you working in a _maven_ project (there is a _pom.xml_)? Tag for language should be "ru"; "RU" is for the country.

Comment: @JoopEggen, no, I unfortunately work without maven

Comment: @JoopEggen, I have files named "locals.properties", "locals_ru.properties", ...

Comment: (Maven would have provided a "fixed" directory structure, which would help us.) Try `"sample.locals"`.

Comment: @JoopEggen, how can this work without maven?

Comment: Forget my mentioning maven; `src/main/java/` as source root would be typically maven, that is why I asked, because the rest was more of a Visual Studio project (`res/`).

Comment: @JoopEggen, I added maven to the project and put the properties files in the resources folder, trying to call   ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("locals",Locale.forLanguageTag("RU"), new UTF8Control());  but the error is the same

Comment: `src/main/resources/sample/locals.properties` implies `ResourceBundle.getBundle("sample.locals")`. BTW In such cases try to find a working demo/example. I am sorry for my late response.

Comment: UTF8Control might have its own slightly deviating logic: try als "/sample/locals" (unlikely) and "sample/locals".